# jQuery blockUI: Blocked elements "show through" another dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog, element, z-index, blockui

I have a page on which I use blockUI to block some elements.  When the user clicks a button on the page, a dialog appears, but the blocks on the underlying page are "showing through" on the dialog.  I have tried using z-index, such as in the following, but that hasn't worked.  How can I stop the blocks from appearing on the dialog?

---

```
function showDialog() {
        $("#imageGallery-modal").dialog({
            width: 1200,
            height: 600,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            zindex: 900000,
            show: 'clip'
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the z-index, blocked the page before opening the dialog, and unblocked the page after the dialog closes.

```
function showDialog() {
        $.blockUI();
        $("#imageGallery-modal").dialog({
            width: 1200,
            height: 600,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            show: 'clip'
        });
        $.unblockUI();
}
```

Comment: No, that did not work.  I had scrolled down, so I thought it had worked, but it did not.  Having to unblock each element and reblock is a pain in the neck.  Anyone know of a simpler way?